# Undefined Method for 'NilClass'

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I know this is an oft' asked question, but I've been struggling to get past it despite research here for a number of hourds. I'm attempting to upload .xlsx documents to my AWS S3 Bucket, however I am receiving this error:

```
Error while uploading the file '' to the bucket '': undefined method `bucket' for nil:NilClass
```

However, I've reviewed my code and the error isn't obvious to me. I'll attach the code in question below.

```
       attr_reader :year,  :month, :data, :bucket_name, :file_name, :path

      def initialize(year:, month:, data:)
        @year = year
        @month = month
        @data = data

      end

      def call
        REPORTS.each do |report|
          data =  generate_report_data(report)
          tmp_path = report_tmp_path(report)
          save_report_to_file(data: data, path: tmp_path)
          upload_file_to_bucket?(bucket_name, file_name, path )
        end
      end


      def generate_report_data(report)
        report_class = "Accounting::Datev::Reports::#{report.to_s.camelize}".constantize
        report_class.new(year: year, month: month).call
      end

      def save_report_to_file(data:, path:)
        prepare_dir(path)
        Accounting::Datev::Utils::ExcelGenerator.new(data: data, path: path).call
      end


      def s3_resource
        @s3_resource ||= ::Aws::S3::Resource.new(access_key_id: Settings.aws_pair&.app_key_id,
                                                 secret_access_key: Settings.aws_pair&.app_secret_key,
                                                 region: Settings.aws_pair&.s3_region)
      end

      def BUCKET_NAME
        @bucket_name = s3.bucket('textract-console-eu-central-1-3469d743-084a-020378550')

      end

      def upload_file_to_bucket?( file_name, path, bucket_name)
        s3 = @s3_resource
        obj = s3.bucket(bucket_name).object('/tmp/test.xls')
        obj.upload_file(path)

        true
        rescue StandardError => e
          puts "Error while uploading the file '#{file_name}' to the bucket '#{bucket_name}': #{e.message}"

      end


      def report_tmp_path(report)
        "/tmp/reports/#{year}/#{month}/#{report}.xls"
      end

      def prepare_dir(path)
        dir = File.dirname(path)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)
      end


    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you didn't tell in which line the exception was raised and you didn't provide the full stack trace.

But at a first glance, there is this `bucket` call:

```
def BUCKET_NAME
  @bucket_name = s3.bucket(...)
end
```

Here you are calling `bucket` on `s3` but an `s3` variable doesn't exist in your code nor an `s3` method. Therefore all calls of that `BUCKET_NAME` method must fail.

Comment: It is going to be this line `obj = s3.bucket(bucket_name)` because the preceding line is `s3 = @s3_resource` which without a call to `BUCKET_NAME` (which is a terrible method name and will fail with `NoMethodError`), `@s3_resource` will be `nil`